# Table filter with PrimeNG

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, primeng

I am trying to implement a filter table (https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/filter), but the JSON that I receive have many levels, exemple:

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "categorie": "nice",
  "place": {
    "rank": "first",
    "person": {
      "name": "Joe"
    }
  }
}
```

And the documentation of the PrimeNG make this in the component:

```
export class DynamicColumnsDemo implements OnInit {

    cars: Car[];

    cols: any[];

    constructor(private carService: CarService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.carService.getCarsSmall().then(cars => this.cars = cars);

        this.cols = [
            { field: 'vin', header: 'Vin' },
            { field: 'year', header: 'Year' },
            { field: 'brand', header: 'Brand' },
            { field: 'color', header: 'Color' }
        ];
    }
}
```

And this on the HTML:

```
<p-table [value]="cars">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of cols">
                {{col.header}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-car>
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let col of cols">
                    {{car[col.field]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

But, How can I put on "field" property a JSON with more levels, exemple:

```
this.cols = [
  { field: 'place.person.name', header: 'Name' },
];
```

I already try N ways to do that and I don't know if this is possible...

If anyone can help me, I thanks!

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that we'd have the same structure for the Car interface but with an additional nested field, like so:

```
export interface Car {
  vin?;
  year?;
  brand?;
  color?;
  price?;
  saleDate?;
  owner?: {
    name?;
    age?;
  };
}
```

And we'd want to search by `car.owner.name`, the way to do it is by creating a custom filter for that specific column.

The columns are:

```
this.cols = [
  { field: "vin", header: "Vin" },
  { field: "color", header: "Color" },
  { field: "price", header: "Price" },
  { field: "ownerName", header: "Owner name" } // The field does not matter
];
```

So the column's content in the HTML file would be:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
    <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
        <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
            <ng-container *ngIf="col.field === 'ownerName'; else simpleTemplate">
                {{rowData.owner.name}}
            </ng-container>
            <ng-template #simpleTemplate>
                {{rowData[col.field]}}
            </ng-template>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

The filter header content for this specific column:

```
    <input *ngSwitchCase="'ownerName'" pInputText type="text" 
           placeholder="Custom - Nested object" 
           (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, 'owner', 'customNestedObj')">
```

Where 'customNestedObj' is actually a new method appended to the FilterUtils class from the library like so (in constructor/ngOnInit):

```
 FilterUtils["customNestedObj"] = (value, filter): boolean => {
      value = value.name;
      return FilterUtils.contains(value,filter);
    };
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablefilter-demo-9v5bhg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Nice your solution, I made a map to equality the object properties at that time.